# Slow copy issue using 2T seagate drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, copy

When I try to copy several files from the HD to a brand new Seagate Drive with 2T (using the USB port) I have faced a very slow copy speed. Things that usually spend some minutes (for instance in another computer with Ubuntu 16.04) may take hours in this computer with Ubuntu 14.04 (although this computer is much faster). I have seen some old posts that present a similar problem has happened with pendrivers and I tried similar solutions, but I was not able to deal with it. I also found some new posts with no answer or definitive solution.

I also tried to download some special drivers from seagate, but they also have not changed the phenomenon.

Is this a issue of the Natilus File Manager? I actually tried to download another file manager called Krusader but although it does not stuck for so long, I realize that some files were not copied!

Is there any kind of expansion drive that is more suitable to work with Ubuntu and these issues do not arise?

I have used Ubuntu for a while and I am able to solve the simplest issues with the help of this forum, but I'm ashamed to admit that I never studied carefully the system. So, I believe I should be treated as beginner.

Answer (score 0):

My seagate drive is one of them with no supply. Since the computer is not very new, I considered the case that maybe this could be the problem (the usb drive did not have enough power to supply the seagate). Thus, I tried an USB adapter with supply and it worked.